# How can I join a base without relationship ?

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm, dql

I have a table User, and a table Company.

The table Companyhas a field user_id, but the table User don't have relationships with company.

If Users had a field company_id, I would have done this request :

```
$queryBuilder
            ->select('u')
            ->join('u.company', 'c')
            ->where('c.name LIKE :name')
        ;
```

But as it doesn't, I don't know how I can do it in Doctrine.
I already done this request the other way around, I can join the table User in my Company repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query must look similar to this:

```
select *
from user u
  join company c
    on u.userId=c.userId
```

The relationship is 1 to n ("1" company can have "n" - many- users, so the primary key from user (userId) is added to company table), so the relationship does exist.

Comment: This is correct but to be useful you should explain why it works

Comment: I was doing it... you didn't let me finish